# Conditional compilation and non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am having trouble understanding non-type template arguments and was hoping someone could shed light on this.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int a>
void f() {
  if (a == 1) {
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
  } else {
    T("hello");
  }
}

int main() {
  f<int, 1>;
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error saying:

```
/tmp/conditional_templates.cc:13:12:   required from here
/tmp/conditional_templates.cc:8:5: error: cast from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
     T("hello");
     ^
```

But, can't the compiler detect that the non-type argument "a" is 1 and hence the else branch won't be taken? Or is that too much to expect? In which case, how do I accomplish something like this?

Comment: I understand the error and there is a fix for it. However, I dont understand what you're trying to do? What does `a` signify in your template parameter list? Why do you *need* this in the first place?

Comment: Remove the "T" from the statement T("Hello") inside the function f(). It is perfectly OK to pass non-types as template arguments. The function call in the main() function should be f<int, 1>();

Comment: I think the OP wants to write the `else` condition to be impossible, and is wondering why the compiler doesn't ignore the error since the second template parameter `1` will trigger the execution of the `if` rather than the `else` statement.

Comment: I wanted to conditionally compile code depending on the value of a variable. Maybe I should have used bool instead of int in my example.

Comment: @Anirudh, that wont make any difference.

Comment: Isn't it compiler-specific? Code compiles and works correctly with ideone: https://ideone.com/.

Comment: @Anirudh You are looking for the "static if". It has eluded C++ so far. This [WG doc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf) is a helpful read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T, int a>
struct A {
    void f() {
        T("hello");
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T,1> {
    void f() {
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
    }
};


int main() {
  A<int,1> a;
  a.f();
  A<int,2> b;
  b.f();
}
```

Now, this uses [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) in order to provide alternative implementations for specific values of the template parameters.

Note that I've used a class, because [function templates cannot be partially specialized](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit I honestly don't see the fundamental reason to do this, but its your code. Apart from the obvious bug (failure to provide parens for the function call in `main()`, and the warning (loss of data converting a char address to `int`), the bigger question regarding conditional inclusion is important.

If you have have code such as:

```
if (something)
{
    do something
}
```

it obviously has to compile, and will *not* do so conditionally. That the `something` is sourced from a non-type template parameter makes no difference. You need to get the logic out of an in-function if-expression and into a template-expansion controlling mechanic instead. Specialization is one such technique, [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) is another:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

static const char* something = "something";

template<class T, bool a>
typename std::enable_if<a>::type f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    std::cout << something << '\n';
}

template<class T, bool a>
typename std::enable_if<!a>::type f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    std::cout << std::hex << T(something) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    f<int, true>();
    f<intptr_t, false>();
}
```

**Output**

```
typename std::enable_if<a>::type f() [T = int, a = true]
something
typename std::enable_if<!a>::type f() [T = long, a = false]
100001f18
```

What you do in each is up to you. Of course you could punt and do much/all of this with preprocessor macros, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in your environment `sizeof(int)` is different than `sizeof(const char*)`.

In such case part of code: `T("hello")` which is in fact `int("hello")` tries to convert `const char*` to `int`. Compiler is complaining because precision would be lost in such a conversion.

To check the sizes of `int` and `const char*`:

```
std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(const char*) << std::endl;
```

`else` branch won't be run when calling `f<int, 1>()` but it does not mean that compiler will ignore errors within `else` code.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 this is not a big secret anymore, however I still thought this is worth mentioning.

With [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) in C++17 the tool you actually wanted to use arrived. Each discarded constexpr if statement inside a templated entity is not instantiated when the template is instantiated. (exceptions apply)

Your snippet only needs minor modifications. (apart from fixes) Mainly the branching had to be inverted to get the troublesome statement into the constexpr if statement.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int a>
void f() {
  if constexpr (a != 1) {
    T("foo");
  } else {
    std::cout << "bar\n";
  }
}

struct Printer
{
    Printer(char const * const msg) {
        std::cout << "Message: " << msg << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
  f<int, 1>();
  f<Printer, 0>();
}
```

This prints

```
bar
Message: foo
```