# Failure to create C++ arrays recursively

Tags: c++

I want to test a recursion method and the following code has a compilation error. I've double checked the subscripts variables, and they should be correct. I really couldn't figure it out, can somebody help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t Size>
void fn(array<T, Size>& data) { 
   const size_t begin{0};
   const size_t end{Size-1};
   const size_t leftUpper{(begin+end)/2};
   const size_t rightLower{leftUpper+1};

   if (data.size() > 1 ) { 
      array<T, end+1-rightLower> right; 
      cout << "Right: " << end+1-rightLower << endl;   
      fn(right);
   }
}

int main() {
   array<int, 5> test;
   fn(test);
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 GuessNumber.cpp -o test
In file included from GuessNumber.cpp:2:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/array: In instantiation of ‘struct std::array<int, 2305843009213693952>’:
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   recursively required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2]’
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 5]’
GuessNumber.cpp:21:11:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/array:94:12: error: size of type ‘std::array<int, 2305843009213693952>’ is too large (‘9223372036854775808’ bytes)
     struct array
            ^~~~~
```

Comment: Did you mean `if constexpr (Size > 1 )` maybe?

Comment: `data.size() == 1` is the base case. It seems at some point, the calculated array size `end+1-rightLower` might becomes negative, which is not in the range of `size_t`, I guess, because when I changed it to `end+1-rightLower+1` it can pass the compilation. I've doubled checked `end+1-rightLower`, and think its value will always be positive, which really confuses me.

Comment: Your `if` is not a `constexpr` so the compiler keeps expanding the template recursively. Once the size drops below `0` it wraps around to huge numbers because `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: `data.size() == 1` is not any sort of base case because it's evaluated at run time, but you are asking the compiler to work out these templates at compile time

Comment: It works, thanks for clarifying this! But the compilation has the warning ` warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
`. Is there any better way to avoid warnings?

Comment: @Neymar87 `if constexpr` is a [C++17 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) and you seem to be compiling with `-std=c++14`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let us understand where the problem comes from.

The error you get

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/array: In instantiation of ‘struct std::array<int, 2305843009213693952>’:
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   recursively required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2]’
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 5]’
```

tells you that you first instantiate `fn` with `Size=5` (because you call it in the `main`), and this recursively instantiates `fn` with `Size=2`. Unfortunately the compiler does not show the full recursion, otherwise you would see that the recursion does not end here.
If you use in the program an array of size 2

```
array<int, 2> test;
```

you will see an additional level of recursion, in the error message:

```
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   recursively required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 1]’
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 2]’
GuessNumber.cpp:21:11:   required from here
```

which again, tells you that the instantiation of `fn` with `Size=2` triggers the intantation of `fn` with `Size=1`. But the recursion does not end here. Try with

```
array<int, 1> test;
```

and you will finally see what is happpening:

```
/usr/include/c++/10.1.0/array: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__array_traits<int, 9223372036854775808>’:
/usr/include/c++/10.1.0/array:110:56:   required from ‘struct std::array<int, 9223372036854775808>’
GuessNumber.cpp:13:33:   required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 0]’
GuessNumber.cpp:15:9:   required from ‘void fn(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&) [with T = int; long unsigned int Size = 1]’
GuessNumber.cpp:21:11:   required from here
```

When `Size=1`, the compiler fully generates `fn`, including the code in the braces `if (data.size() > 1)`. Even if this condition is always false, still the code is parsed and compiled. This means that, inside the never-executed-code, you instantiate `fn` with `Size=0`. But then, you have an overflow in the variable `end`, which attains a large value. Then the code after `if` instantiates an `std::array` with the exceedingly large size.

To fix this, you need to stop the compiler from generating code when `Size=0`.
This can be done in several ways.

With c++17 you have a very convenient [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If). If the condition of `if constexpr` is not true, the code is not instatiated at all, ending then the template recursion. So you can substitute

```
if (data.size() > 1 ) {
```

with

```
if constexpr (Size > 1 ) {
```

And compile with `std=c++17`. Notice that I changed the condition to `Size > 1` because the `data` variable is not `constexpr`, hence you cannot use it at compile time.

If you do not have c++17, you can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t Size>
typename std::enable_if<(Size == 0)>::type fn(array<T, Size>& data) { }

template <typename T, size_t Size>
typename std::enable_if<(Size > 0)>::type fn(array<T, Size>& data) { 
   const size_t begin{0};
   const size_t end{Size-1}; // 1
   const size_t leftUpper{(begin+end)/2}; // 0
   const size_t rightLower{leftUpper+1}; //  1

   if (data.size() > 1 ) { 
     array<T, end+1-rightLower> right; // 1
      cout << "Right: " << end+1-rightLower << endl;   
      fn(right);
   }
}

int main() {
   array<int, 5> test;
   fn(test);
}
```

The two approaches are perfectly equivalent, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065446/if-constexpr-vs-sfinae).

Comment: Thanks for the great analysis!

Comment: If you declare `fn` as a function object then you can use partial specialization, which makes your last snipped more readable: `template <class T, size_t N> struct Fn; template <class T> struct Fn<T, 0> { void operator()(array<T, 0> &data) {} };`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

// the function contains its body just because looks like 
// you want to implement some other logic there
template <typename T>
void fn(array<T, 2ul>& data) {
      const size_t Size = 2;
      const size_t begin{0};
      const size_t end{Size-1};
      const size_t leftUpper{(begin+end)/2};
      const size_t rightLower{leftUpper+1};
      array<T, end+1-rightLower> right; 
      cout << "Right: " << end+1-rightLower << endl;   
}

template <typename T>
void fn(array<T, 1ul>& data) {
}

template <typename T>
void fn(array<T, 1ul>& data) {
      const size_t Size = 1;
      const size_t begin{0};
      const size_t end{Size-1};
      const size_t leftUpper{(begin+end)/2};
      const size_t rightLower{leftUpper+1};
      array<T, end+1-rightLower> right; 
      cout << "Right: " << end+1-rightLower << endl;   
}

template <typename T, size_t Size>
void fn(array<T, Size>& data) { 
   const size_t begin{0};
   const size_t end{Size-1};
   const size_t leftUpper{(begin+end)/2};
   const size_t rightLower{leftUpper+1};

   if (data.size() > 1 ) { 
      array<T, end+1-rightLower> right; 
      cout << "Right: " << end+1-rightLower << endl;   
      fn(right);
   }
}

int main() {
   array<int, 5> test;
   fn(test);
}
```

You code is not compiled conditionally. `if`s do not work like you expect when you do template magic. One more example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29814814/667580)

Comment: Thanks for the code, it inspired me! The code works well for `array<int, 5> test;`, but not other cases like `array<int, 15> test;`

Comment: Yeah my fail, one more corner case is when size = 1 comes